# How to get data from pins other than the control signals pins?

Tags: c, unix, serial-port, gps, termios

I have a GPS module, it has control signals pins such as RX and TX, however, it has also two other pins named `3D fix` and `1PP (1 pulse per second)`. How can I get data from those two pins without using Arduino?

I'm using `termios` and `unistd` unix libraries to do serial programming. I'm also using usbuart converter between the GPS module and my laptop.

Comment: Most serial interfaces support just a few signals additional to TX and RX. You might like to consider to wire "3D fix" and "1PP" to some of CTS, DSR, DCD, RI, ... Some of them can be read. Read the documentation! Do some experiments!

Comment: Read the data sheet... often there is also document named something like "Programmers Guide" for the component.

Comment: OT: Reading from a "1PP" pin seems strange. It sounds more like a pin used at HW level  as a trigger signal